# Make a program that calculates the sum of the first 20 Fibonacci numbers

Tags: function, pointers, fibonacci

I need to write a program that has the sum of the first 20 fibonacci numbers. Using two functions that summon the size and the sum of the 20 numbers. This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    int fib[20] = {0,1};    
    int *fib_ptr = &fib[2];  
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        *fib_ptr = *(fib_ptr - 1) + *(fib_ptr - 2);
        fib_ptr++;
     }
    for(int x = 0; i < 20; x++)
        printf(“%4d”, fib[x]);
    printf(“\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

I know this just makes the fibonacci numbers and not the sum.

Comment: There's a typo in the second `for` loop, the condition should be `x < 20`. And the first `for` loop condition should start with `int i = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `printf` at the end, just add those numbers when looping through at the end.

```
Sum += fib[x]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity to the people who edit these comments if mine, how do I get the styling to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    int fib[20] = {0,1}, *fib_ptr = &fib[2], x, i, sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        *fib_ptr = *(fib_ptr - 1) + *(fib_ptr - 2);
    sum += *(fib_ptr-2);        
    fib_ptr++;
     }
    //for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
        //printf("%4d", fib[x]);
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate everything just once. Have

```
int result = 1; // fib[0] + fib[1]
```

and after every calculation loop add new value in it

```
result += *fib_ptr;
```

and your array needs to be size 2

```
int fib[2] = {0,1}; // index it with fib[i%2] in loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Since

> Fib[n+1] = Fib[n]+Fib[n-1],

so also

> Fib[n-1] = Fib[n+1]-Fib[n],

so that the sum of Fibonacci numbers can be written as a telescoping sum, where in the end

> Fib[1]+...+Fib[n] = (Fib[3]-Fib[2])+(Fib[4]-Fib[3])+...+(Fib[n+2]-Fib[n+1])
>
> = Fib[n+2]-Fib[2] = Fib[n+2]-1

If n is large, one can thus use a halfing-and-squaring algorithm to compute Fib[n+2] and compute the sum without computing the Fibonacci numbers in between.